# AngularJS - a nice loader idea, but can't figure out how to do it

Tags: angularjs

I looked for a nice loader directive, and thought of a cool idea, but I don't know how to make it happen.

When having the code:

```
<div loader="loaderVariable">
   <div>staff and things</div>
</div>
```

I want it to show a loader inside that div, until loaderVariable becomes false. When it does, it hides the loader and shows the things acctualy inside the main div:

```
<div loader="true">
   Loading...
</div>
<div loader="false">
   <div>staff and things</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this (with a directive)?

Comment: You should at least try to "make it happen". Paste here some Angular code and, if you'll have difficulties, you'll receive help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That directive already exists, it is called `ngShow` :)

```
$scope.isLoading = true;
```

usage

```
<div ng-show="isLoading">
   Loading...
</div>
<div ng-show="!isLoading">
   <div>staff and things</div>
</div>
```

---

**Update**. Here is a directive that hides the content and shows an ajaxLoad icon. Once the variable passed to the directive is set to false, it will hide the icon and show the content :

```js
.directive('ngLoading', function() {
  return { 
    transclude: true, 
    templateUrl : 'ngLoading.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
      scope.$watch(attributes.ngLoading, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (!newValue) {  
          element[0].querySelector('.loading-ajaxLoad').style.display = 'none';
          element[0].querySelector('.loading-content').style.display = 'block';
        }  
      })           
    } 
  } 
});
```

Template, edit it for your needs :

```html
<img class="loading-ajaxLoad" width="20" src="http://press.solarimpulse.com/img/ajax_loader.gif"/>
<div ng-transclude class="loading-content"></div>
```

Additional CSS :

```css
.loading-content {
  display: none;
}
```

Example usage markup, `ng-loading` could be set on the `<table>` element as well :

```html
<div ng-loading="isLoading"> 
  <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="data in data">
       <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
       <td>{{ data.position }}</td>
       <td>{{ data.office }}</td>
     </tr>       
  </table> 
</div>
```

Example usage script :

```js
$scope.isLoading = true; 
$scope.data = null;

$http({ 
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/4dq3j'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  $scope.data = response.data;
  $scope.isLoading=false;
})
```

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/DiXnlmqLtj5cYQvDVQRw?p=preview**

Comment: If i wanted do this, I could even use two directives. ng-show & ng-hide.
I just wondered, if there is a way to do it like I suggested, so my code will be cleaner for me to look at :)

Comment: @Amit, OK - have updated the answer with a directive and an example using a `$http` source to populate a `<table>`.